# Dovecot + Roundcube + One Time Password Authentification = Possible?

Tags: security, webmail, roundcube

As stated in the topic, I would like to install the dovecot imapserver, and enable web-access via the roundcube-client. 
To heighten security when logging in from unsecure machines, I would like to login via One Time Passwords (e.g. OPIE). 
Would that be possible? 
Does anyone have experience implementing such a feature into to a webmail client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is a bit old, but should a good guide whatever two-factor auth system you choose. To get two-factor authentication working on linux, your best bet is to go through PAM.  Point PAM to your two-factor auth server via pam-radius, pam-ldap etc.

http://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-configure-webmail-for-wikid-strong-authentication/?searchterm=imap

There's also a [feature request](http://trac.roundcube.net/ticket/1484130) to allow SASL OTP in Roundcube.

hth

nick

Answer (score 1):

[FYI, there is a One-Time Password plugin for SquirrelMail](http://www.squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=276) (OTPs generated in the webmail layer, but can use an optional static prefix deployed via external means).

[There is also an authentication plugin that can be configured, amongst other things, to make SquirrelMail SSO-aware](http://www.squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=34) (how helpful that is to this question depends on how strong the authentication is for the SSO system).